# JSON, list might be empty - what type?

Tags: python, json, type-hinting

I want to specify an object which has a `prizes` property. This might either be a list of `PrizeInfo` objects, or an empty list. I'm looking for a schema something like the code below, except this returns the following error:

```
"MySchema": {
    "properties": {
        "prizes": {
            "type": "List['PrizeInfo', 'null']",
        }
    }
 }

E   TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.List; actual 2, expected 1
```

I am using these templates to generate Python classes.

Comment: Do you mean to use type hinting? Then `'null'` is not a valid type hint anyway, you'd use the Python object `None`.

Comment: And `List[]` can't specify the size of the list, so `List[PrizeInfo]` would already allow an empty list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFTDH_8.5.7/com.ibm.wbpm.wid.integ.doc/topics/rjsonnullunsempprops.html. 'null' is a valid type in JSON.

Comment: But type hinting is **not JSON**.

Comment: You are specifying Python syntax in a JSON string, **not** JSON syntax in that string. And JSON would use `null`, not the Python string `'null'`. Don't mix the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no annotation for an 'empty' list. Any empty list object will satisfy a `List[...]` type hint, regardless of the specifics of what the list contents must be.

So if an empty list is allowed, use

```
List['PrizeInfo']
```

That allows for any list with 0 or more elements, so the empty list is included in that hint.

If you instead meant to say that `None` values (`null` in JSON) are permitted next to `PrizeInfo` objects, then use a [`Union[...]` annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) with `None`:

```
List[Union['PrizeInfo', None]]
```

If you wanted to say that either `None`, or a list of `PrizeInfo` objects is permitted (in JSON terms, a `null` or an array), then use

```
Union[List['PrizeInfo'], None]
```

You could also use [`Optional[...]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional):

```
Optional[List['PrizeInfo']]
```

to mean the same thing. I'd not use that inside the `List[...]` hint, however; that reads as if you are saying that the type of the elements might be optional, making for a confusing type specification.

Comment: After all, all elements of `[]` are of type `PrizeInfo`. :)